# Как присвоить значение переменной в зависимости от состояния RadioButton

Tags: android

Как при выборе пользователем пола (муж/жен), присвоить значение (`double`) для переменной, в зависимости от выбранного муж. или жен. в `RadioButton`?

Comment: Извините, а почему  double?

Comment: @0xdb, а это принципиально? может быть там коэффициент берется, и для М\Ж он разный.

Comment: можете значения double записывать в свойство Tag для каждого radioButton, а потом его получать в зависимости от выбраного radioButton

Comment: @AndreyMihalev Не знаю, поэтому и спросил. А вы как думаете, имеет это отношение к вопросу?

Comment: Именно так- там коэффициент для м и ж  разный;  double потому что коэффициент,  спасибо за совет попробую с Tag, я просто еще совсем джуниор, не ругайтесь особо если неправильно вопрос поставил)